# Unresolved Class: FileProvider -- Using Downloaded JAR

Tags: android, module, android-fileprovider

I've downloaded `support-v4-24.1.1.jar` and am trying to use `FileProvider`,  however, `android:name` inside of the manifest is not detecting it. This is all within an Android Module so I can use it inside of Unity.

I looked inside the jar and Android >> Support >> V4 >> Content >> FileProvider.class exists. So I don't know why I'm  getting an unresolved class error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**Android Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.fileproviderplugin">

<application>
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="gov.navair.aurora.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

**Build.Gradle (module level)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28


defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation files('libs/support-v4-24.1.1.jar')
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That library is a few years old and probably should no longer be used. And `implementation` is the wrong directive to use for code that you are exporting from a module.

Try this instead:

```
api "com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0"
```